# Duplicate objects in API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use infinite scroll by doing this:

[image]

And it's working properly. However, when I pass the data to the stickers state and then do the mapping, the first items of the call are duplicated. Example:

[image]

Note that the gifs are duplicated. However, infinite scroll is working correctly. When it runs, it makes a new call with new gifs and adds them to the screen without repeating them. Only these early state firsts start out duplicates. The code is like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Please add code as *text*, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like every gif has an `id` so you just need a way to [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out all those new items where their id doesn't already exist in the current array of items.

```
// Accept the current array of gifs, and a new array of gifs
function dedupeGifs(gifs, newGifs) {
  
  // `map` over the current array of gifs
  // to create an array of ids
  const gifsIds = gifs.map(gif => gif.id);

  // `filter` out all those gifs that don't
  // already exist
  return newGifs.filter(gif => {
    return !gifsIds.includes(gif.id);
  });
}
```

Then merge the current array, and the deduped array together:

```
const dedupedItems = dedupeGifs(gifs, newGifs);
setState(prev, [ ...prev, ...dedupedGifs ]);
```